# Can I stop the water in my basement?

Tags: water

I'm digging out my basement and am seeing water flow in because the water table is very high right now. My thoughts are that once I cemented the basement and created a sealed box so to speak the water would not come in. My neighbor disagrees and says the water will lift the cement floor. I've dug down 3 feet so far and prior to this dig out I only had water come in on occasion, not nearly what I'm seeing now. I find it hard to believe that 3 feet of compressed dirt would prevent water and 12 inches of concrete would not.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to make an existing basement deeper, turn a crawl space into a basement, or digging for a new basement?

Comment: I'm making an existing basement deeper

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely clear what you are asking. If the water table is 3' from the surface, I agree with your neighbor...a basement is a bad idea.

Concrete is porous so in and off itself will do absolutely nothing to stop the water. You can waterproof it by applying a rubber based membrane to the outside, but with a high water table, it will always try to find a way in. You'd have to definitely install French drains and a sump pump as well.

Comment: +1, without proper drainage and waterproofing, you will be building an inground pool! Your neighbor is right.

Comment: i dont think the water table is 3' from the surface. I was 3 feet down all summer and didn't see water. Only recently with the recent storm I can see that the water table is quite high. The lake around the corner is at its highest edge.

Comment: wait...there's a lake around the corner? That's another strike against a basement being a good idea in this location.

Comment: The lake is 1.5 miles and down a hill